# Quadtree search in Python omitting regions

Tags: python, c, quadtree

I have an issue with a quadtree class I wrote in Python. I use the quadtree to efficiently cross-correlate large (100,000+ entries) catalogs of data and the match cataloged that I get out of the quadtree is omitting large regions of the catalog. This is the entire quadtree code. The functions relevant to matching up sources are nearersource() and nearestsource(),

```
import math

import geom_utils as gu

MAX = 60
class Quadtree(object):
    """
    Quadtree base class. Only functions that are agnostic to
    the type of coordinate system or source object used. Must
    use a subclass.
    """
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        self.top = Node(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)


    def inserttonode(self, node, source):
        if len(node.contents) == MAX:
            self.subdivide(node)
        if node.q1:
            self.inserttoquad(node, source)
        else:
            # If no subquads exist add source to the list in CONTENTS element
            node.contents.append(source)

    def inserttoquad(self, node, source):
        if source.x >= node.xmid:
            if source.y >= node.ymid:
                quadrant = node.q1
            else:
                quadrant = node.q4
        else:
            if source.y >= node.ymid:
                quadrant = node.q2
            else:
                quadrant = node.q3
        self.inserttonode(quadrant, source)

    def subdivide(self, node):
        node.q1 = Node(node.xmid, node.ymid, node.xmax, node.ymax)
        node.q2 = Node(node.xmin, node.ymid, node.xmid, node.ymax)
        node.q3 = Node(node.xmin, node.ymin, node.xmid, node.ymid)
        node.q4 = Node(node.xmid, node.ymin, node.xmax, node.ymid)
        # Pop the list and insert the sources as they come off
        while node.contents:
            self.inserttoquad(node, node.contents.pop())

    def match(self, x, y):
        return self.nearestsource(self, x, y)

    def nearestsource(self, tree, x, y):
        nearest = {'source':None, 'dist':0}
        nearest['dist'] = self.initial_dist(tree.top.xmax, tree.top.xmin,
                                       tree.top.ymax, tree.top.ymin)
        interest = {'xmin':x-nearest['dist'], 'ymin':y-nearest['dist'],
                    'xmax':x+nearest['dist'], 'ymax':y+nearest['dist']}
        interest = gu.clip_box(interest['xmin'], interest['ymin'],
                               interest['xmax'], interest['ymax'],
                               tree.top.xmin, tree.top.ymin,
                               tree.top.xmax, tree.top.ymax)
        nearest['dist'] = nearest['dist']*nearest['dist']

        self.nearersource(tree, tree.top, x, y, nearest, interest)
        return nearest['source']

    def nearersource(self, tree, node, x, y, nearest, interest):
        self.num_nearersources+=1
        if gu.intersecting((node.xmin), (node.xmax),
                           (node.ymin), (node.ymax),
                           (interest['xmin']), (interest['xmax']),
                           (interest['ymin']), (interest['ymax'])):
            if node.q1 == None:
               for s in node.contents:
                    s_dist = self.norm2(s.x, s.y, x, y)
                    if s_dist < nearest['dist']:
                        nearest['source'] = s.source
                        nearest['dist'] = s_dist
                        dist = math.sqrt(s_dist)
                        interest['xmin'] = x - dist
                        interest['ymin'] = y - dist
                        interest['xmax'] = x + dist
                        interest['ymax'] = y + dist
                        interest = gu.clip_box(interest['xmin'], interest['ymin'],
                                           interest['xmax'], interest['ymax'],
                                           tree.top.xmin, tree.top.ymin,
                                           tree.top.xmax, tree.top.ymax)
            else:
                self.nearersource(tree, node.q1, x, y, nearest, interest)
                self.nearersource(tree, node.q2, x, y, nearest, interest)
                self.nearersource(tree, node.q3, x, y, nearest, interest)
                self.nearersource(tree, node.q4, x, y, nearest, interest)

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        self.xmin = float(xmin)
        self.ymin = float(ymin)
        self.xmax = float(xmax)
        self.ymax = float(ymax)
        self.xmid = float((self.xmin + self.xmax)/2.0)
        self.ymid = float((self.ymin + self.ymax)/2.0)
        self.q1 = self.q2 = self.q3 = self.q4 = None
        self.contents = []

class Point(object):
    """
    The point of Point (heh.) is to have a uniform object that
    can be passed around the Quadtree. This makes for
    easy switching between equatorial and pixel coordinate
    systems or different objects.
    """
    def __init__(self, source, x, y):
        self.source = source
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

class ScamPixelQuadtree(Quadtree):
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        super(ScamPixelQuadtree, self).__init__(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

    def insert(self, source):
        self.inserttonode(self.top, Point(source, source.ximg, source.yimg))

    def norm2(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        return gu.pixnorm2(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    def initial_dist(self, x2, x1, y2, y1):
        return  min(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)/1000.0

class ScamEquatorialQuadtree(Quadtree):
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        super(ScamEquatorialQuadtree, self).__init__(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

    def insert(self, source):
        self.inserttonode(self.top, Point(source, source.ra, source.dec))

    def norm2(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        return gu.equnorm2(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    def initial_dist(self, x2, x1, y2, y1):
        return  min(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)/100.0
```

I tried making the MAX value extremely large, essentially turning the tree into a fancy array and the matching worked fine (albeit slow). So I think the problem is likely in the nearersource() function, the part that controls whether we descend into a region to do the actual comparisons but I can't figure out what.

I wrote this same code in C, the exact same algorithm, and it works fine. No region omission. So I've been trying to think of language specific reasons why the alogorithm would work in C but not Python. The first thing that came to my mind is precision so I tried using the BigFloat package for the parts in the code that control whether the code goes into a region or not, but it didn't help. Are there any other differences in C or Python that could cause this issue in Python?

Comment: Not a solution, but your code uses dictionaries where at least I would use something else, i.e. tuples or even [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s.

Comment: Can you expand on that? I've never worked with tuples but I just looked them up and there didn't seem to be an obvious reason why tuples would be better than dictionaries.

Comment: Every named property look-up that you do requires computation of the hash of the property name, and searching. With a `namedtuple` that doesn't happen, so it can be faster.

Comment: Oh, very cool. The quadtree does run too slow right now but I've just been focused on getting it working right in Python that I haven't put any attention into optimizing. Thanks for the tip!